# Unable to resolve module 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign''

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am facing following issue when import this:

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

Error:

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign` from `/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/react-native-elements/src/helpers/getIconType.js`: Module `react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:161:1460)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
    at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
    at Array.map ()
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
    at /Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:212:33
    at Generator.next ()
    at step (/Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
    at /Users/amit/Desktop/development/cbcvp-rn/cbcvp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:473
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░ 38.0% (719/1166), failed.

how to fix this error anyone help me...

Thanks

Comment: did the issue fixed? I am getting same issue

Answer (score 3):

Run the below commands

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons
npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Link your library if not linked by using react-native-link. Also try clearing cache and restarting your Metro Bundler. This sometimes occurs after installing any library. Please let me know if it works. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

react-native link

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons
npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

while linking; error No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

error EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E://android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I was having this problem for many hours but I figured it out late. It was a stupid mistake at my end. The solution is to **run cmd as admin**

```
npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

and success Assets have been successfully linked to your project

Answer (score -2):

yarn add react-native-vector-icons

react-native link react-native-vector-icons

hope work for you