# react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign could not be found within the project-Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing following issue.

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign` from `node_modules/react-native-elements/src/helpers/getIconType.js`: react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign could not be found within the project.
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "GeoLocation",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-fused-location": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-get-location": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I have done all the steps which mentioned in following link.

[Unable to resolve module 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212413/unable-to-resolve-module-react-native-vector-icons-antdesign)

Comment: Have added font list in `android/app/build.gradle` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have seen your code i would like to tell you that first you should edit your `package.json`  and upgrade the `react-native-vector-icons` version
`"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",`
to
`"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",`,then delete your node module folder and then run npm install command, and then import vector icons in your file like this:-

```
import AntDesign from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign"
```

if you still face any problem fell free to ask again.